# Not able to delete the foreign key contraint in Nhibernate Mappings

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

```
public class ReviewMap : ClassMapBase<Review>
    {
        public ReviewMap()
        {
            Table("Reviews");

            List(x => x.Objectives, m =>
            {
                m.Table("Objectives");
                m.Cascade(Cascade.All.Include(Cascade.DeleteOrphans));
                m.Key(k => k.Column("ReviewId"));
                m.Where("DeletionDate is null");
                m.OrderBy("OrderNo");
                m.Index(x => x.Column("OrderNo"));
                m.Inverse(true);
            }, m => m.OneToMany());
        }


public class ObjectiveMap : ClassMapBase<Objective>
    {
        public ObjectiveMap()
        {
            Table("Objectives");

            // Use "soft deletes" to allow us to capture results against deleted items
            Where("DeletionDate is null");
            SqlDelete("update Objectives set DeletionDate = getutcdate(), OrderNo = 1 where id=?");

            ManyToOne(x => x.Review, m =>
            {
                m.Column("ReviewId");
                m.NotNullable(true);
            });

            Property(x => x.Details, m =>
            {
                m.NotNullable(true);
                m.Length(1000);
                m.Column("Details");
            });

            Property("OrderNo", m =>
            {
                m.NotNullable(false);
            });

        }
    }
```

When I try to delete the Reviews then It gives me the error for Foreign key constraint in Objective table. as ReviewId is foreign key in Objectives table.

Can you suggest what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You prevent deletions in the Objectives table with your custom sql-delete but also require that all Objectives have a reference to a Review row. How should this work? This would also require that Reviews are never deleted.

A way this can work would be if you remove the foreign key constraint on the Objectives.ReviewId column, but I wouldn't recommend that. Since the ID of a deleted Review row won't help you for history purposes, a better way would be to make the Objectives.ReviewId column nullable and also null it out in your custom sql-delete.

Comment: okay Thanks a lot. I will discuss what type of approach our requirements needs. I really appreciate your help :-) Thank You

Comment: even if i change the sqldelete(update changed to ReviewId=null. but it still gives me the same error

Comment: @Moiz You should check which SQL statements are executed by NHibernate by either using NHibernate's statement logging or a SQL/NHibernate profiler.

Comment: I am facing another issue. can you please help me :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557352/how-to-set-the-expectation-on-sqldelete-in-nhibernate-mapping